# RadioListButton Doesn't update C# .net

Tags: c#, .net

```
        if (textBox3.TextLength > 0)
        {

            radioListButton1.ClearSelected();
        }
```

> I have this code but when the condition it's true radio list button
>   doesn't update automatically...It stays checked.

Comment: Could you show us the method you are calling this code from? Are you calling this code from an event handler? When `radioListButton1` should be cleared, after `textBox3` text is changed, or after some other user's action?

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are running the code 'on server':

```
<script runat="server">
    if (textBox3.TextLength > 0)
    {
       radioListButton1.ClearSelected();
    }
</script>
```